# Continuity of a Linear function

Tags: functional-analysis

Continuity of a function always is my problem, I know a theorem about that : Given two normed vector spaces V and W (over the same base field) a linear map $A:V \to W$ is continuous if and only if there exist a real number $C$ such that $\|Av\|\le C\|v\|$ for all $v\in V$.
But I do not know how apply this theorem, and I am not sure that I am assuming correct theorem. for example we have:
$f(x)\to f(0.5)$ as linear functional on $(\mathcal C[0,1] , \|.\|_\infty)$
how could I show its continuous.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must exhibit $C$ such that $\|Tf\|\le C\|f\|_{\infty}$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm on the normed space in which $Tf$ lives.

In our case, $Tf=f(0.5)\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, you want $|f(0.5)|\le C\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$. But it is clear that $C=1$ is a possible bound. Indeed, $|f(0.5)|\le \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ cause $|f(0.5)|$ is a member of the set where we are taking $\sup$.

So, we have $\|Tf\|\le C\|f\|_{\infty}$ for all $f$ taking $C=1$.

Comment: In this question if we $||.||_\infty$ change to $||.||_2$ what will happen?

Comment: @Shalaleh: The operator $T$ will not be bounded in $(\mathcal C [0,1],\|\cdot\|_2)$: Consider the sequence of characteristic functions $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n}\chi_{(0.5-\frac{1}{2n}, 0.5+\frac{1}{2n})}(x)$, which get thinner and higher, but maintaining the squared area under the curve. We have $\|f_n\|_2=1$, but $T(f_n)=\sqrt{n}$, which violates the boundedness of $f$.

Comment: Why we should consider the sequence of characteristic function? please explain more.

Comment: In general I have problem with finding bound for a norm, for example we have : $ sup \frac {||\int ^1 _0 k(x,y) f(y) dy ||_\infty}{||f||_\infty}$$ \le sup ||\int ^1 _0 k(x,y) f(y) dy ||_\infty $. I could not understand why we assume $||f||_\infty = 1$.